# Google App Engine vertical scaling

Tags: cloud-hosting, scaling, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I know Google Cloud (Google App Engine) can autoscale instances horizontally: you have 1 server with certain parameters, when it's overloaded autoscaler launches new server and balances load between them.

But I can't find any informations if Google Cloud provides vertical scaling. Ex. you have one server with 2 cores, 4GB RAM, it's overloaded so autoscaler gives you more resources (your server gets more RAM / more cores -> your server is 4 cores, 8gb RAM and it is not overloaded any more). 
Is this possible using Google Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I recieved an answer from Sharif Sharaf - moderator on GCE Group on G+. Maybe it'll be helpful for someone as it was helpful for me:

(tl;dr: no, there is no vertical autoscaling builded in. It's possible. It's hard. Don't use it until you have idle IT dept.)

> For App Engine you should check out the documentation for the Modules
>   API which allows you to choose between manual, basic and automatic
>   (horizontal) scaling and specify the instance class in your module
>   .yaml file. See:
>
> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration
>
> For Compute Engine you could consider using the load balancer in
>   combination with an orchestration engine like Ansible to automate
>   changes to the size of your instances. This would take a fair bit of
>   work to set up initially though and horizontal scaling is by far the
>   simpler solution. A description of the automation solution can be
>   found here:
>
> http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/05/using-ansible-to-automate-google.html

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing says there are 9 types of machines available for standard environment, so I was wondering how does it know which machine to start, and once it starts one, does it ever change to a new one if there is more demand? The documentation didn't list much besides that about how it scales vertically. There's also this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard so I'm guessing what he means is that it starts an F1 instance all of the time if you don't list one.